# TCP Sockets send buffer size efficiency

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, tcp, network-programming

When working with WinSock or POSIX TCP sockets (in C/C++, so no extra Java/Python/etc. wrapping), is there any efficiency pro/cons to building up a larger buffer (e.g. say upto 4KB) in user space then making as few calls to send as possible to send that buffer vs making multiple smaller calls directly with the bits of data (say 1-1000 bytes), other the the fact that for non-blocking/asynchronous sockets the single buffer is potentially easier for me to manage.

I know with recv small buffers are not recommended, but I couldn't find anything for sending.

e.g. does each send call on common platforms go to into kernel mode? Could a 1 byte send actually result in a 1 byte packet being transmitted under normal conditions?

Comment: Each send call is a kernel call.  But kernel calls do not correspond to individual packets, unless you've disabled packet coalescing.  I suggest you read about the Nagle algorithm.

Comment: Well nagle looks like it creates more problems than it solves... Assuming wikipedia is right, a "send(1);send(1000);" will still send a 1 byte packet initially, a send-send-recv in a request-response protocol may get stuck till the previous ack (and with a delayed ack on the other end might be some time)... So is the actual answer that one should forget nagle and send large buffers (to avoid kernel switches and undersized packets)?

Comment: Indeed, the wikipedia article strongly recommends you buffer writes yourself and disable Nagle.  Reduced cost of kernel calls is another benefit.

Comment: OK, but the information I can find is still not entirely clear. e.g. without Nagle I would want to know what the MSS value is for a connection, and with it Id want some sort of flush method that doesn't seem to exist (also MSDN seems to suggest MS deprecated TCP_NODELAY in WS2.x, but I can't find anything more on that)...

Comment: Just buffer as much as you can and send it in one send. Several K is a common value. You don't have to worry about the MSS. The real reason to reduce send() calls is to reduce context switching into the kernel.

Answer (score 4):

As explained on *TCP Illustrated Vol I*, by Richard Stevens, TCP divides the send buffer in near to optimum segments to fit in the maximum packet size along the path to the other TCP peer.  That means that it will never try to send segments that will be fragmented by ip along the route to destination (when a packet is fragmented at some ip router, it sends back an IP fragmentation ICMP packet and TCP will take it into account to reduce the MSS for this connection).  That said, there is no need for larger buffer than the maximum packet size of the link level interfaces you'll have along the path.  Having one, let's say, twice or thrice longer, makes you sure that TCP will not stop sending as soon as it receives some acknowledge of remote peer, because of not having its buffer filled with data.

Think that the normal interface type is ethernet and it has a maximum packet size of 1500 bytes, so normally TCP doesn't send a segment greater than this size.  And it normally has an internall buffer of 8Kb per connection, so there's little sense in adding buffer size *at kernel space* for that (if this is the only reason to have a buffer *in kernel space*).

Of course, there are other factors that force you to use a buffer *in user space* (for example, you want to store the data to send to your peer process somewhere, as there's only 8Kb data in kernel space to buffer, and you will need more space to be able to do some other processes)  An example:  ircd (the Internet Relay Chat daemon) uses write buffers of up to 100Kb before dropping a connection because the other side is not receiving/acknowledging that data.  If you only **write(2)** to the connection, you'll be put on wait once the kernel buffer is full, and perhaps that's not what you want.

The reason to have buffers in user space is because TCP makes also flow control, so when it's not able to send data, it has to be put somewhere to cope with it.  You'll have to decide if you need your process to save that data up to a limit or you can block sending data until the receiver is able to receive again.  The buffer size in kernel space is limited and normally out of control for the user/developer.  Buffer size in user space is limited only by the resources allowable to it.

Receiving/sending small chunks of data in a TCP connection is not recommendable because of the increased overhead of TCP handshaking and headers impose.  Suppose a *telnet connection* in which for each character sent, a header for TCP and other for IP is added (20 bytes min for TCP, 20 bytes min for IP, 14 bytes for ethernet frame and 4 for the ethernet CRC) makes up to 60 bytes+ to transmit only one character.  And normally each tcp segment is acknowledged individually, so that makes a full roundtrip time to send a segment and get the acknowledge (just to be able to free the buffer resources and assume this character as transmitted)

So, finally, what's the limit?  It depends on your application.  If you can cope with the kernel resources available and don't need more buffers, you can pass without havin buffers in user space.  If you need more, you'll need to implement buffers and be able to feed the kernel buffer with your buffer data when available.

Comment: But without a user space buffer, in the write one char at a time, even with nagle the first packet and any other following a complete ack would have a 1 byte payload? So that is clearly not a good thing, and that applies for any write upto the current MSS doesn't it? So when I know I am going to have upto say 200KB of data generated I want to send,  it still seems I need to ensure I always try to send() more than the largest packet so that TCP wouldn't send initially undersized packets? And the send-send-recv block seems to be a breaking issue that requires working around or disabling nagle?

Comment: Not exactly... You have to consider slow start and window negotiation.  Even so, your tcp probably won't send anything until the next clock tick (depending on the implementation) and you can have added to the buffer tons of data by that time.  Even with/wihout nagle.

Comment: Indeed, in normal implementations, tcp just begins sending an almost empty segment (only the SYN flag is present on it, no data in packet, even if you have some data to send already)

Comment: Nagle algorithm is nonsense to consider, if someone is considering allocating a buffer to send data in chunks.  Nagle consists on waiting to send data if some non-acknowledged data remains in buffer (normally to the next clock tick), instead of sending it inmediately.  Clock ticks happen to issue each 1000th of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a one byte `send` can - under very normal conditions - result in sending a TCP packet with only a single byte payload. Send coalescing in TCP is normally done by use of [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm). With Nagle's algorithm, sending data is delayed iff there is data that has already been sent but not yet acknowledged.

Conversely data will be sent immediately if there is *no* unacknowledged data. Which is usually true in the following situations:

- The connection has just been opened
- The connection has been idle for some time
- The connection only received data but nothing was sent for some time

In that case the first `send` call that your application performs will cause a packet to be sent immediately, no matter how small. So starting communication with two or more small `send`s is usually a bad idea because it increases overhead and delay.

The infamous "send send recv" pattern can also cause really large delays (e.g. on Windows typically 200ms). This happens if the local TCP stack uses Nagle's algorithm (which will usually delay the second send) and the remote stack uses [delayed acknowledgment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment) (which can delay the acknowledgment of the first packet).

Since most TCP stack implementations use both, Nagle's algorithm *and* delayed acknowledgment, this pattern should best be avoided.